# Date range slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am struggeling to make a data range slicer which only shows the months and not specifics dates.
I am not intrerested in having to choose from speficific dataes like 1/7-2023 to 1/8-2023
I would like that it just showed month names link July - August.

Not sure that it is possible to fix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a caledar table using DAX function CALENDARAUTO() and select month from Date hierarchy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Range slicer only support date format or number format. Text cannot put into range slicer type, only click.

If you do not want  dates slicer as 1/7/2023, then you can try to use month numbers:

```
Month=MONTH([Date])
```

[image]